# What's wrong with this simple jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".rpxnow").click();
});
</script>
```

I've put this into the body part of my page, in order to click on all links with class rpxnow. If I paste that line into the javascript console, it produces the desired effect, however, when I reload the page, it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: would be better if you paste html.

Comment: How are the links being added to the page? Is it loaded in via js or is are they sent as part of the document?

Comment: Maybe the click event is not supported at DOM-ready? Why do you wish links to be automatically clicked before the page is even rendered?

Comment: try putting an alert() inside document ready function and check if it executes.

Comment: why are you trying to click something immediately on load?

Comment: Have you tried binding to the "load" event on `$('body')` instead of the "ready" event?  (Just a hunch.)

Comment: what is the code for the click? and is that code wrapped in `$(function(){/*code*/}` tags?

Comment: How are the click events defined? Can you post a sample on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @maniator: The code is in the question and yes it is in the `ready` callback.

Comment: @Felix. that .click() doesnt do anything. there is no function call

Comment: @maniator: Of course. `.click()` is the function call: http://api.jquery.com/click/. But I realized to you probably wanted to know where the click handlers are defined. Is this correct?

Comment: @Felix -- and where is it that he defines WHAT that click does?

Comment: @maniator: I understand you now. Anyway, he says that it works from the console, so it does not seem to be a problem with the handlers.

Comment: @Felix -- i added my answer on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/9FruC/

Answer (score 0):

well... `.click()` is not really supported in all browsers, it will only trigger the click event (not the actual click) in eg. FF.

But if you ar clicking all links use `$("a.rpxnow")`. If you are loading the links in dynamically, then you should probably wait xx seconds before you fire the click thingy.

Comment: He is using jQuery, it is jQuery's `click` function: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @Felix: I know, but even jQuerys `.click()` doesnt actually click the element in all browsers (believe me i tried). It, however, triggers the click event of the selected elements.

Comment: What's the difference between clicking and triggering the click event (besides maybe mouse position)?

Comment: @Flex Kling: well by triggering the click event you fire of any methods bound to that element, but you are NOT firing any build in mechanics, that the element might have eg. following the links HREF or submitting, when clicking a submit-button. Some browsers allow this, but not all. FF i very strickt in what you are allowed to do by code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your current script doesn't return anything. you need to define what the click does:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".rpxnow").click(function(){
      alert('hi!');
      //other code...
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: *If I paste that line into the javascript console, it produces the desired effect.* So there seems to be a click handler defined. Maybe it is an inline handler, we don't know.

Comment: well he did not provide it. im working with what was provided